# For loop in R is printing twice

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm fairly new to programming and am avidly trying to learn R. I am attempting to solve the classic "Fizzbuzz" problem in R and have almost figured out a way, but my loop is printing twice. Tried debugging and searching, but I can't seem to find anything. Any suggestions?

tl;dr Do you know why this for loop prints twice?

```
fizzbuzz = function(n){
  if ( n %% 15 == 0 ) {
    print("Fizzbuzz")
  } else
  if ( n %% 5 == 0 ) {
    print("buzz")
  } else
  if ( n %% 3 == 0 ) {
    print("Fizz")
  } else {
    print(n)
  }
}

for (a in 1:100)
  print(fizzbuzz(a))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you call `print` twice, once in the function and once in the loop.  Remove the `print` in the loop and it only prints once.

```
for (a in 1:100)
  fizzbuzz(a)
```

Comment: Thank you. As I'm sure it is in most cases; solution is simple, I'm an idiot.

Comment: @bstockton: you're welcome. Don't worry, we are all idiots... just in different subjects. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the result of fizzbuzz and inside the function. Try this:

```
for (a in 1:100)
    fizzbuzz(a)
```